# sh.exe": git: command not found

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I recently started using Bitbucket for some projects within my company and am having trouble with git. Whenever I use any command such as git, I receive this error:

```
sh.exe": git: command not found
```

If it helps, I'm using Git Bash.

Comment: how are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a [similar issue with Sourcetree](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/25141825/how-to-make-sourcetree-work-with-the-latest-git-for-windows), with a [pending ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-3704) for requesting to support the actual git bash.

Simply unzip [`PortableGit-2.6.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.6.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.6.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and call `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.0-64-bit\git-bash.exe`: you will have a bash in which git is definitively *not* a "command not found".

Edit:

```
Anand@Anand-PC MINGW64 /C/Documents and Settings/Anand/Documents/2993-privacy-cube
$ ls
css/  images/  index.html  js/  ref/

Anand@Anand-PC MINGW64 /C/Documents and Settings/Anand/Documents/2993-privacy-cube
$ git add *
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No error

Anand@Anand-PC MINGW64 /C/Documents and Settings/Anand/Documents/2993-privacy-cube
$ git commit -m "css changes"
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No error
```

Comment: Hey VonC! Thanks for the response. This solved the command not found error, but now it says I don't have a working directory. See the edit I made to your post. :)

Comment: @A.Pat you can edit your question, not my answer. Is there a .git folder in `/C/Documents and Settings/Anand/Documents/2993-privacy-cube`? Can you try a `git add .` (dot instead of '`*`')